# ceph-mds pod fails to launch with Insufficient cpu, MatchNodeSelector, PodToleratesNodeTaints

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I tracked down the CPU usage. Even after increasing the number of nodes I still get a persistent scheduling error with the following terms: Insufficient cpu, MatchNodeSelector, PodToleratesNodeTaints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hint came from [this article](https://medium.com/@alejandro.ramirez.ch/reserving-a-kubernetes-node-for-specific-nodes-e75dc8297076#.89g4zwx51). It mentions:

> Do not allow new pods to schedule onto the node unless they tolerate
>   the taint, but allow all pods submitted to Kubelet without going
>   through the scheduler to start, and allow all already-running pods to
>   continue running. Enforced by the scheduler.

The configuration contains the following.

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ceph-mds
      namespace: ceph
      labels:
        app: ceph
        daemon: mds
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        node-type: storage
    ... and more ...
```

Notice the `node-type`. I have to `kubectl label nodes node-type=storage --all` so I can label all nodes with `node-type=storage`. I could also choose to only dedicate some nodes as storage nodes.

In `kops edit ig nodes`, according to this [hint](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/742#issuecomment-282245900), you can add this label in the following.

```
spec:
  nodeLabels:
    node-type: storage
```